# Get imgs from post to supersized with output php/wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, supersized

I've got WordPress and I need to include Supersized but I've got a problem about images.

I need to make multiple strings (based a numbers images of post) into jQuery code, through PHP:

```
{image : 'http://....jpg'},
```

for example, this is the post, container of images:

```
<div id="container_post">
<img src="http:....jpg" />
<img src="http:....jpg" />
</div>
```

and, through PHP, I need to make multiple strings into tag `slides:[]`:

```
<script>
[...]

Slides :[
   {image : 'http:....jpg'},
   {image : 'http:....jpg'},
]

[...]
</script>
```

---

i've this code into page php.

i need to get images from this post with this string through php `query_posts('page_id=170');` .

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(function($){

                    $.supersized({

                        // Functionality
                        slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                        autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                        start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                        stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                        random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                        slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
                        transition              :   5,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                        transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                        new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                        pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                        keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                        performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                        image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                        // Size & Position                         
                        min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                        min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                        vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                        horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                        fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                        fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                        fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                        // Components                           
                        slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                        thumb_links             :   0,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                        thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                        slides : [ 
                                      {image : 'http://....jpg'},
                                      {image : 'http://....jpg'},
                                      etc

] , 

                        // Theme Options               
                        progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
                        mouse_scrub             :   0

                    });
                });

            </script>
```

and i want generate same string `{image : 'http://....jpg'},` each by images, into line `slides: []`

---

i seen this old code...but it get only thumbnail...i need the images and multiple strings.

```
   slides : [  <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            $post_array = Array();
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',false); 
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb[0], false); 
                $thumb = $thumb[0]; 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $post_array[] = "{image : '".$thumb."'}";
                } 
            }
            echo implode(",",$post_array);
        }
    ?> },
```

all into the string: `slides : []`

---

I've a problem.

I need insert the titles of imgs:

for example:

```
{image : 'http://***.jpg', title : 'title_img'}
```

Can you help me how?

ps: i have this modded code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){
                var imagesArray = [
                <?php 
                function foo($anArray){
                foreach($myimages as $img){
                    echo "\{image : '".$img."'\},";
                }
                }?>
                ];
                $('#container_post img').each(function(){
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.image = this.src ;
                    imagesArray.push(obj);
                });
                $.supersized({

                    // Functionality
                    slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                    autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                    start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                    stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                    random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                    slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                    transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                    transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                    new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                    pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                    keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                    performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                    image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                    // Size & Position                         
                    min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                    min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                    vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                    horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                    fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                    fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                    fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                    // Components                           
                    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                    thumb_links             :   0,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                    thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                        slides : imagesArray 
, 

                    // Theme Options               
                    progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
                    mouse_scrub             :   0

                });
            });

        </script>
```

Thank you,
Frank

Comment: how are the images, stored in the post? are they all uploads?

Comment: the images are uploaded by a Media gallery of wordpress and published in a post, all generated by php. hope you understand :S...it's so hard to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically in your view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var imagesArray = [
<?php
  foreach($myimages as $img){
    echo "\{image : '" . $img . "'\},";
  }
?>
];
    api.options.slides = imagesArray;
});
</script>
```

Comment: i've this error: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/web/htdocs/www.***.com/home/l22/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/index.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />, why? i don't know why that in the local root (from pc) it work...but from server don't.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to create an array that will hold the Objects key "image" with the images paths values:

```
var imagesArray = [];

$('#container_post img').each(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.image = this.src ;
    imagesArray.push(obj);
});

// console.log( JSON.stringify(imagesArray) );  // UNCOMMENT TO TEST IN CONSOLE

// USE LIKE:
$.supersized({
    slides : imagesArray 
});
```

Comment: How can i insert this code? i've tried into or out from script of Supersized.